# Hide items in the right-click context menus in Visual Studio 2010 (08)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, contextmenu, right-click

The right-click context menus of the source editor, the project items and the solution item, is getting ridiculously long, and two of them even have scrolling now on my 1680x1050 screen.

Is there any way for me to hide items on these menus, even if I have to add an event to my Visual Studio macro-system and find and hide them manually?

Here's examples, many of these items I **never** use:

[image: context menus]

**Edit1:** The current answer + comments suggest I should use the Customize menu item in the toolbar context menus, go to the second tab, Commands, and use the Context Menus radio selection and find the relevant menus there.

Here are 3, which are suggested by comments:

[image: customize context menus]

As you can see, they're all empty.

**Edit2:** After clicking the "Reset All" button in that dialog, for the Solution and Project menus, I got items in the dialog, that I could edit, but the changes did not affect the actual context menu on either a project or the solution file. Also, after restarting Visual Studio, the dialog contents for those two were again empty.

Answer (score 36):

In Visual Studio 2010 you can:

1. Goto Tools->Customize
2. Select the Commands tab
3. Select the Context menu radio button
4. Select the appropriate context menu from the dropdown list to the right, and delete away

I believe Visual Studio 2008 is similar.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an editable list for the source code menu, the only one, Editor Context Menus, have 2 items, Code Window and XAML Editor. The menu item "Surround with", found in the rightmost menu in my question is nowhere to be found. There was a "Surround with" entry in the XAML editor menu, but that didn't have any effect on the main code editor context menu. Could these be 100% dynamically generated? Seems odd with all those other menus in there.

Comment: I can't find the "Open Command Prompt" entry either, so there seems to be a lot missing here.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have the Open Command Prompt menu item. That may be added by an extension. Things are definitely a bit dynamic, since items are being removed that are out of context. I'd imagine items could be added by extensions as needed also.

Comment: Yeah, I notice that ReSharper seems to do the "right thing" by adding a lot of menu items in here that I can delete, but yes, most of those items I want to get rid of probably comes from extensions. Problem is, those extensions add things I want, so I can't just get rid of the extension either.

Comment: I do see Command Prompt in the Solution Explorer's context menu. Those are under "Project and Solution Context Menus | Item".

Comment: @Lasse - you haven't found the right context menu.  Use the combobox next to the "Context menu" radio button.  Pick "Project and Solution Context Menus | Project" and | Solution.

Comment: @Hans, Project and Solution are completely empty for me, no Controls listed. I did (again, this must be the 4th time I look through this list) exactly as you said, I picked "Project and Solution Context Menus | Solution": no controls. Then I moved up to find the Project selection (second in the "Project and Solution Context Menus" group), no controls there either.

Comment: @Lasse - that's Really Bad.  Post a screenshot if you want to make sure that you're in the right spot.  Next is Tools + Import/Export, Reset for the big hammer.

Comment: @Hans, Added a screenshot of the Editor, Solution and Project (in their respective groups) dialog box, as you can see, I have nothing in there. Am I still looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Strange, it takes a second to populate but I see several entries in "Project and Solution Context Menus | Solution".

Comment: Ai ai, I clicked Reset All when having the solution menu shown, all items appeared now.

Comment: *Sigh*, but alas, editing that menu makes no difference to the actual menu appearance. I also tried restarting Visual Studio, makes no difference.

Comment: And after restarting Visual Studio, the menus in that dialog are again blank.

Comment: Unfortunately, you may need to reset your VS installation or reinstall. See [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/549920/the-project-and-solution-context-menus-project-context-menu-appears-blank-in-the-customize-dialog-and-causes-errors) Connect bug.

Answer (score 14):

You will need to choose the correct context menu in the **Customise** option.

Go to Tool > Customise,

Then choose the Context menu as you did in your **Edit1** screenshots but choose "`Editor Context Menus | Code Window`" from the dropdown menu instead.

[image]

From there you should be able to delete whatever command you don't need from your context menu. Next, for the other commands that can't be found in Editor Context Menus | Code Window (mostly plug-ins or extensions related commands) you will have to go through other categories.

For example, I am using CodeMaid and when I right click a file in *Solution Explorer* the context menu below are shown

[image]

In order to remove the '*Cleanup Selected Code*' command I will have to choose the `Project and Solution Context Menus | Solution Folder` dropdown option.

**Added**: Here is my sample reduced context menu (removed *Copy*, *Cut*, *Paste*, *Outline* Menu and *Create Snippet...*)

[image]

Hope this helps =)

Edit: In case you want to add back the commands you removed you can either add them back using **New Command...** or just press **Reset All**. Keep in mind the later will restore all the commands. Thus unless you are really having trouble finding the removed command use the first method.

Answer (score 1):

I use 3 VS extensions and these 3 are responsible for polluting the context menu:

1. VSCommands
2. Power Commands
3. Power Toys

**Using their own options dialogue**, it's possible to subject showing those menus to pressing CTRL (in VS Commands) or completely disable them (the other 2 extensions)