# How to prevent F# Interactive from automatically opening on right-click?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2015, f#-interactive

Whenever I right-click on any bit of code in Visual Studio 2015, the F# Interactive window pops open.  While I appreciate that F# has a REPL, this is pretty annoying on space-constrained screens like laptop.

Does anybody know how I can prevent this behavior?  I am perfectly happy to open F# Interactive myself when I need it.

Comment: this is not the default behavior - so my guess is that you bound some command to your RMB

Comment: That is entirely possible, but I just installed VS2015, so unless it imports settings from VS2013, I'm not sure how one would do this.

Comment: have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315812/hide-items-in-the-right-click-context-menus-in-visual-studio-2010-08?

Comment: @DanBarowy I experience the same issue after installing VS2015. What I did is just move FSI window to a part that I can unpin, so it won't take any screen space.

Comment: @kimsk: that seemed to do the trick for me.  Perhaps you should provide an answer so that I can give you credit.

Comment: @OrlandoWilliam, I tried looking through the context menu customization menu, but... there are a LOT of options!

Comment: @DanBarowy glad that it solves your issue. I post it as an answer now.

Comment: very same issue here. i consider this a bug.

Comment: This has been bugging me for months! I didn't realise that if I just leave the FSI window there after it has popped up, after that Right-Click works as normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experience the same issue after installing VS2015. What I did is just move FSI window to a part that I can unpin, so it won't take any screen space.

[image]