# How to remove elements from the context menu in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, ide

How to remove elements from the context menu in Visual Studio? I am not using all of this items, how can I still just some of them?

[image]

Comment: related: [Hide items in the right-click context menus in Visual Studio 2010 (08)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5315812/11107541)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2017 this procedure will work:

- Open "Tools" menu
- Click "Customize..."
- Click the "Commands" tab
- Click the "Context menu" radiobutton
- From the combobox on the right select the context menu you want to change
- Now you should have the following dialog showing where you can remove/add items from the context menu:
  [image]